# Does neo4j have something like primary key/object id?

Tags: c#, neo4j

I need an efficient way of getting to a specific node from some type of ID. For example, the website will have a URL like https://website.dev/board/9e88d2717bb64639

Then "9e88d2717bb64639" (just an example) should quickly be able to find the correct node in the neo4j database. How is this done?

I know there is an 'ID' field, however upon further research I found out that it is not as reliable as one would want. It is crucial that this is done as efficiently as possible, since these node look-ups will happen frequently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an indexed property on your node. UUIDs will work. You can use the function [randomUUID()](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/scalar/#functions-randomuuid) to generate a unique random UUID, and set that on a node during its creation. If you have an index on the label/property then lookup should be quick.

Comment: Thank you! It all makes sense now.